# Weird behavior of Dart code in Windows

Tags: windows, dart, dart-io

The Dart project I'm working on requires multiple instances print statements without new lines. As I understand that printing without a new line in dart can be achieved via

```dart
stdout.write("string");
```

All is fine but when I'm trying to write code similar to this:

```dart
stdout.write("Enter a number: ");
var a = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: SYSTEM_ENCODING);
stdout.write("Enter another number: ");
var b = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: SYSTEM_ENCODING);
stdout.write(a + b);
```

This is running perfectly on non Windows systems but in Windows (32 and 64 bits) the second message I'm printing is not showing up and the program is directly going to the stdin.readLineSync() call and waiting for input. After I give the input the message is shown. I came across similar posts here saying that stdout.write() may be async but what's weird is that this code runs perfectly fine and in synchronous manner on Linux.

Synchronous execution is very much needed in my project and the above problem can be solved via Futures but will lose the sync execution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdout does not flush until a new-line character, on many platforms. I think this is true for Windows as well.

Currently the API does not expose a way to force a `fflush` on `stdout`.

I would recommend that you file a feature request at http://dartbug.com/new.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `stdout.flush()` `before stdin.readLineSync()` ?

Comment: tried this:

stdout.write("Enter a number: ");
stdout.flush();
var a = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: SYSTEM_ENCODING);
stdout.write("Enter another number: ");
stdout.flush();
var b = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: SYSTEM_ENCODING);
stdout.write(a + b);

Its giving this error:

Unhandled exception:
Bad state: StreamSink is bound to a stream

on the second stdout.write()

Comment: also as far as i know stdout.flush() returns a Future right? I would then have to write my subsequent code in a .then() block right? That kind of defeats my purpose of having a Sync Execution.

Comment: Yes, it's async. I guess it's better to get comfortable with async execution because sync doesn't have broad support in Dart.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RononDex you are sure that this is no answer? Maybe it is.

Comment: Your "answer" ends with a question mark, so yes I am sure

Comment: @RononDex: that is just a weird way of putting the intent of "try this". But "have you tried this" can still be an answer. Gunter, please stick to formatting your answers as statements though.